# Probabilistic distance to sample mean

Tags: probability, self-study, statistical-significance, bayesian, sampling

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be independent random variables from $\mathbb{P}$ bounded by the interval [0,1]. We define the empirical mean of these variables by

\begin{align}
\overline X = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \cdots + X_n).
\end{align}

Is there a way to get

a) the distribution of the distance between a point $x$ and the mean $\mathrm{E}[\overline X]$ as $\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{E}[\overline X] -x)$ and

b) a probabilistic inequality like

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(|x - \mathrm{E}[\overline X]| \geq r) \leq ?
\end{align}

both, given the sample mean $\overline X$?

---

I want to tell if $x$ is inside the ball with center $\mathrm{E}[\overline X]$ and radius $r>0$. Since $\mathrm{E}[\overline X]$ is unknown and only estimated by $\overline X$, need a probabilistic statement weather $x$ is inside or outside this ball.

Comment: If this is a self-study question, please add the tag. Are you aware that $\mathbb{E}[\overline X]=\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ ? And do you know of probability inequalities like [Cebycev's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) or [Markov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov's_inequality)'s?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the equality, but I do not know $E[X_1]$, but only an estimate thereof and hence my question.

Comment: Since your questions do not ask about $X-\bar{X}$ but about $X-\mathbb{E}[\overline X]$, I suggest you rephrase it as you really mean it, although I do not see how you plan to use a probability inequality on $X-\bar{X}$.